# How to prevent new line when using awk

Tags: variables, awk, newline

I have seen several variations of this question, but none of the answers are helping for my particular scenario.

I am trying to load some files, adding a column for filename.  This works fine only if I put the filename as the first column.  If I put the filename column at the end (where I want it) it creates a new line between $0 and the rest of the print that I am unable to stop.

```
for f in "${FILE_LIST[@]}"
do
awk '{ print FILENAME,"\t",$0 } ' ${DEST_DIR_FILES}/$f > tmp ## this one works
awk '{ print $0,"\t",FILENAME } ' ${DEST_DIR_FILES}/$f > tmp ## this one does not work
mv tmp ${DEST_DIR_FILES}/$f
done > output
```

**Example data:**

-- I'm starting with this:

```
A       B       C
aaaa    bbbb    cccc
1111    2222    3333
```

-- I want this (new column with filename):

```
A       B       C       FILENAME
aaaa    bbbb    cccc    FILENAME
1111    2222    3333    FILENAME
```

-- I'm getting this (\t and filename on new line):

```
A       B       C
        FILENAME
aaaa    bbbb    cccc
        FILENAME
1111    2222    3333
        FILENAME
```

**Bonus question**
I'm using a variable to pass the filename, but it is putting the whole path.  What is the best way to only print the filename (without path) ~OR~ strip out the file path using a variable that holds the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly a line endings issues as your `awk` script a syntactically correct. I suspect your files in `"${FILE_LIST[@]}"` came from a Windows box and have `\r\n` line endings. To confirm the line endings for a given file you can run the `file` command on each file *i.e.* `file filename`:

```
# create a test file
$ echo test > foo      

# use unix2dos to convert to Windows style line endings
$ unix2dos foo       
unix2dos: converting file foo to DOS format ...

# Use file to confirm line endings
$ file foo       
foo: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

# Convert back to Unix style line endings
$ dos2unix foo
dos2unix: converting file foo to Unix format ...

$ file foo
foo: ASCII text
```

To convert your files to Unix style line endings `\n` run the following command:

```
$ for "f" in "${FILE_LIST[@]}"; do; dos2unix "$f"; done
```

**Explanation:**

When the `FILENAME` is the first string on the line the carriage returns `\r` effectively does nothing as we are already at the start of the line. When we try to print `FILENAME` after any other characters we see the effects that we are brought to the start of the next line, the TAB is printed then the `FILENAME`.

*Side note:*

`Awk` has the variable `OFS` for setting the output field separator so:

```
$ awk '{print $0,"\t",FILENAME}' file
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
$ awk '{print $0,FILENAME}' OFS='\t' file
```

**Bonus Answer**

The best way *I.M.O* to strip the path of file is to use the utility `basename`:

```
$ basename /tmp/foo
foo
```

Using [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME}' $(basename /tmp/foo)
foo
```

Comment: PERFECT!!! It was CRLF, so it worked after converting it.  This is my first time trying awk, so I never would have figured that out on my own.

Comment: +1. The problem with the external `basename` approach as shown, though, is it'd only work if you were in the directory where the file exists. I'd just do `awk '{fname=FILENAME; sub(/.*\//,"",fname); print fname}' /tmp/foo`.